# Fastlane Gym Errors on GitHub Actions

Tags: xcode, github-actions, fastlane

I'm setting up Fastlane with GitHub Actions, and currently getting this error:

```
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.70]: All required keys, certificates and provisioning profiles are installed 
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.70]: Setting Provisioning Profile type to 'app-store'
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.70]: Debug: Building the project with gym...
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: -----------------
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: --- Step: gym ---
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: -----------------
WARN [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: Lane Context:
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:mac, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:mac, :LANE_NAME=>"mac beta", :KEYCHAIN_PATH=>"~/Library/Keychains/***", :BUILD_NUMBER=>"2", :SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE=>"app-store", :MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING=>{"***"=>"match AppStore *** macos"}}
INFO [2023-09-18 20:50:44.73]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/Users/runner/work/client-app-swift/client-app-swift/fastlane/README.md'

+------+---------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform          | 0           |
| 2    | create_keychain           | 0           |
| 3    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
| 4    | increment_build_number    | 3           |
| 5    | match                     | 5           |
|    | gym                       | 0           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

ERROR [2023-09-18 20:50:44.84]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
Search query: undefined method `to_sym' for nil
```

This seems to be the specific error:

```
ERROR [2023-09-18 20:50:44.84]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
Search query: undefined method `to_sym' for nil
```

This is the Fastlane file I'm using:

```rb
# Fastfile
default_platform(:mac)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain #{name}...")
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  UI.message("Debug: Creating temporary keychain #{name}...")
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  if password.nil? || password.empty?
    UI.error("Error: Password for temporary keychain is missing.")
  end
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

platform :mac do
  lane :beta do
    UI.message("Debug: Starting the beta lane...")
    
    keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
    keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD

    UI.message("Debug: Ensuring temporary keychain...")
    ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

    UI.message("Debug: Validating keychain variables...")
    if keychain_password.nil? || keychain_password.empty?
      UI.error("Error: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD is not set.")
    end

    UI.message("Debug: Creating App Store Connect API key...")
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
      issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
      key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,
      duration: 1200,
      in_house: false
    )
    
    UI.message("Debug: Incrementing build number...")
    increment_build_number
    UI.message("Debug: Build number incremented.")

    UI.message("Debug: Printing variables before match function...")
    UI.message("Debug: App Identifier: #{APP_IDENTIFIER}")
    UI.message("Debug: Git Authorization: #{Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION)}")
    UI.message("Debug: Keychain Name: #{keychain_name}")
    UI.message("Debug: Keychain Password: #{keychain_password}")
    UI.message("Debug: API Key: #{api_key}")

    UI.message("Debug: Running match...")
    match(
      type: 'appstore',
      app_identifier: "#{APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION),
      readonly: false,
      keychain_name: keychain_name,
      keychain_password: keychain_password,
      api_key: api_key,
      verbose: true 
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Building the project with gym...")
    gym(
      configuration: "Release",
      project: "Meter.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "Meter",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER 
        }
      },
      verbose: true  
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Uploading to TestFlight with pilot...")
    pilot(
      apple_id: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_ID}",
      app_identifier: "#{APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
      skip_submission: true,
      distribute_external: false,
      notify_external_testers: false,
      ipa: "./Meter.ipa",
      verbose: true  
    )

    UI.message("Debug: Deleting temporary keychain...")
    delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)

    UI.message("Debug: Beta lane completed successfully!")
  end
end
```